# Scrolling Vertical Parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, scroll

I'm working on a simplified vertical parallax (similar to http://nikebetterworld.com).

I've got a [quick demo working](http://bit.ly/mYTzAB) - the code technically works, but I'm getting a jittery effect on the repaint after each scroll - it seems like the javascript is happening late. Any idea why? I can't see anything in the script that really stands out.

```
var getYPosition = function() {
  if (typeof(window.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
    return window.pageYOffset;
  } else {
    return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }     
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  var sections = $(".section");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var x = getYPosition(),
    y = Math.floor(x / 1600),
    z = $(sections[y]).offset();
    $(sections[y]).css("background-position", "0 " + (getYPosition() - z.top)/2 + "px");
  });
});
```

Comment: Good LORD, that's annoying.  Can we let this fad die quickly?

Comment: I looked at that while drunk, and it was NOT a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the images are being moved twice - first by the browser scroll, and then by your `scroll()` handler. Hence the jitter.

You might get a cleaner effect by using `position:fixed` or `background-attachment:fixed` for the images - this way they are unaffected by the browser scroll, but will be moved by the `scroll()` handler.  You'll no longer have one effect fighting with the other.  You'll have to modify your `scroll()` handler accordingly.

Comment: background-attachment: fixed; I didn't even know that property existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should check if your scroll callback is being called too often. If this is the case, you can try using setInterval to limit the number of rerenderings:

http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

```
var outerPane = $details.find(".details-pane-outer"),
    didScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
        didScroll = false;
        // Check your page position and then
        // Load in more results
    }
}, 250); //in miliseconds
```

Comment: Not quite what's needed for this problem, but a good technique. Thanks.

Comment: Undersocre.js, which you should consider using for any non-trivial JavaScript project, has a method that does that for you called `throttle`.